# node-gyp on Windows: can't find unicode libraries

Tags: windows, npm, include-path, node-gyp, node-stringprep

I'm trying to install `node-xmpp-core` on my Windows system using npm.

(I had tried using cygwin, but it node-gyp would not exit cleanly when configuring.)

I'm using the standard windows cmd prompt.  My command is:

```
> npm install node-xmpp-core --msvs_version=2013
```

The error I get is "..\node-stringprep.cc(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unicode/unistr.h': No such file or directory".  (Full output below.)

Since I know that the compiler must be looking for this file, I downloaded the ICU libraries and set the INCLUDE environment variable:

```
> set INCLUDE
INCLUDE="C:\Program Files (x86)\icu\include"
```

What's going on?

I know from multiple web searches, on SO and other places, that everything involving node-gyp on Windows is potentially fragile.  But this seems so elementary.

---

Full gyp output (with essential npm output also):

```
> node-stringprep@0.5.4 install C:\Users\jgruenhu\My Documents\code\centenario\jxgProj\node_modules\node-xmpp-core\node_modules\node-stringprep
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\jgruenhu\My Documents\code\centenario\jxgProj\node_modules\node-xmpp-core\node_modules\node-stringprep>node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
  node-stringprep.cc
..\node-stringprep.cc(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unicode/unistr.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\jgruenhu\My Documents\code\centenario\jxgProj\node_modules\node-xmpp-core\node_modules\node-stringprep\build\node_stringprep.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\jgruenhu\My Documents\code\centenario\jxgProj\node_modules\node-xmpp-core\node_modules\node-stringprep
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.31
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok


npm ERR! node-stringprep@0.5.4 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-stringprep@0.5.4 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-stringprep package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-stringprep
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "node-xmpp-core" "--msvs_version=2013"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\jgruenhu\My Documents\code\centenario\jxgProj
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.23
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jgruenhu\My Documents\code\centenario\jxgProj\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```